# LdapConnection Bind Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

Is there a way to set the **bind** timeout on an LDAP connection using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection` that comes with .NET? Not to be confused with the **connection** timeout (which is the [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.timeout?view=netframework-4.6.1#System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_LdapConnection_Timeout) property). Essentially, I need to set the `LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/session-options).

[LdapSessionOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapsessionoptions?view=netframework-4.6.1) seems like the place for that, but near as I can see this particular option isn't present. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: looking for similar problem in .net core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
private const int LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT = 0x04;

[DllImport("Wldap32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "ldap_set_optionW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int ldap_set_option([In] IntPtr handle, [In] int option, [In] ref int inValue);

private static void SetLdapConnectionBindTimeout(LdapConnection conn, int timeoutSeconds)
{
    // We need the underlying LdapConnection handle; that's internal, so reflection here we go.
    var handleField = typeof(LdapConnection).GetField("ldapHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var handleWrapper = handleField.GetValue(conn);

    // That handle object is itself a wrapper class around the IntPtr we actually need.
    // The wrapper class is internal, and so is the IntPtr, so more reflection.
    var internalHandleField = handleWrapper.GetType().GetField("handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var internalHandle = (IntPtr)internalHandleField.GetValue(handleWrapper);

    // Now we can set. 
    ldap_set_option(internalHandle, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, ref timeoutSeconds);
}
```

This works, but I certainly don't love all that reflection. Or the `DllImport`, although the .NET library uses that under the covers anyway, so I feel like that's not as big a deal.

Per the comments below, it's also good to note here that due to the dependency on `Wldap32.dll`, this would appear to be Windows-only and not suitable for cross-platform.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, specifically for an MFA scenario that occurs during the .Bind call and needing more than the default 30 secs.

Comment: Awesome, hope this helped. That's exactly what I was dealing with as well.

Comment: this is a good solution but only to .net framework (windows specific). looking for same in .net core

Comment: This does indeed not seem to work for Linux, since it mentions `"Wldap32.dll"`. Guessing a corresponding version would be needed for `libldap`, assuming it even has this field.

Comment: Thanks to you both, that's a good point -- updated the answer to make the Windows-only limitation clearer.