# LDAPConnection Bind timeout in .net core

Tags: .net-core, ldap

I am unable to found anything for LdapConnection Bind timeout in .net core. one solution is [LdapConnection Bind Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385657/ldapconnection-bind-timeout) but it is not working in .net core.
LdapConnection timeout and bind timeout seems to be different thing.
my code is something like following

```
   var credentials = new NetworkCredential(obj.AdminBindUserName, obj.AdminBindPassword);

            if (obj.LDAPAddressPort.HasValue && obj.LDAPAddressPort > 0)
            {
                connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(obj.LDAPAddress, obj.LDAPAddressPort.Value, false, false));
                //connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(obj.LDAPAddress, obj.LDAPAddressPort));connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(obj.LDAPAddress, obj.LDAPAddressPort));
            }
            else
            {
                connection = new LdapConnection(obj.LDAPAddress);
            }
             //connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);   
            connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
            connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;           
            connection.Bind(credentials);
```

I have tried connection timeout but looks like no effect of it.
I am getting exception message ExceptionCode: 81,Message: The LDAP server is unavailable at random time interval. sometime 18 seconds, sometime more then a minute.
I am reproducing the problem via help of vpn connectivity. my local ldap is connected via first connecting to some vpn.
with vpn connection every thing works fine. but without vpn my call to Bind() method wait indefinitely

Comment: Anyone can help me in this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do exactly with timeout. " _The LDAP server is unavailable at random time interval._" If your ldap server is unstable, that's an issue to resolve first. I would try to 1. ssh to the machine who runs slapd, then ldapwhoami at random time interval and check the response time, if ok then 2. ssh to the machine running .net and do the same thing, or just telnet ldap and again check the response time to see if it's a server or a network issue.

Comment: My simple question is during Bind there shouldn't be infinite time to wait. There should be some bind timeout property which will do it internally. you can look in the referenced post which do it but via dllimport. telnet to the machine is one option i would also do as a workaround but that meant before every call i have to first telnet then do actual call. also sometime we got ldpa server url not in ip format. then there will be additional work. some additional details are added in the post

Comment: Ok. Setting a timeout is one thing, but it will not prevent the root issue, my suggestions were just meant to help troubleshooting, they are not workaround.

Comment: By setting timeout my api call will have some max time interval to get the response. indefinite bind waiting is sort of a show stopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timeout can be set using Task and once that timeout in second is reached a cancellation event will occur to get out of this as show below

```
if (obj.IsBindTimeLimit)
            {
                int timeoutSecond = obj.BindTimeOutInSeconds;
                if (timeoutSecond <= 0)
                {
                    timeoutSecond = 5;
                }
                CancellationToken tscancel = new CancellationToken();
                Task t = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(obj.AdminBindUserName, obj.AdminBindPassword);
                    if (obj.LDAPAddressPort.HasValue && obj.LDAPAddressPort > 0)
                    {
                        connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(obj.LDAPAddress, obj.LDAPAddressPort.Value, false, false));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connection = new LdapConnection(obj.LDAPAddress);
                    }                  
                    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                    connection.Bind(credentials);
                });
              
                if (!t.Wait(timeoutSecond * 1000, tscancel))
                {                    
                    throw new TimeoutException("The timeout interval elapsed");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(obj.AdminBindUserName, obj.AdminBindPassword);
                if (obj.LDAPAddressPort.HasValue && obj.LDAPAddressPort > 0)
                {
                    connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(obj.LDAPAddress, obj.LDAPAddressPort.Value, false, false));
                }
                else
                {
                    connection = new LdapConnection(obj.LDAPAddress);
                }               
                connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                connection.Bind(credentials);
            }
```